# Find the substring of an element in the String array at index

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, populate

The `main` is supposed to break up first and last name and store the last name in a new array. There is a logical error in my code, because this portion does not print.

```
package names;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class names {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        final int TOTALNAMES=15;
        String [] names = new String[TOTALNAMES];
        String [] firstname = new String[TOTALNAMES];

        //String
        File file = new File ("Names12.txt");
        Scanner  read = new Scanner (file); 
        printHeading();

        int i, cntr=0;
        while(read.hasNext()&&cntr<TOTALNAMES){
            cntr++;
            read.nextLine();
        }
        String[] name = new String[cntr];
        Scanner  read1 = new Scanner(file); 
        for( i = 0; i<name.length; i++) {
             name[i] = read1.next();

             //System.out.println(name[i]);
        }
          //creating new string array to hold last name values
        int j;
        String[] lastname = new String[name.length];
        for(j = 0; j < lastname.length; j++){
            lastname[j]=names[i].substring(name[i].indexOf(" "+1));
             System.out.println(lastname[j]);
    }
}

    //This method prints the heading centered
    public static void printHeading () {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tTable of Names");
    }
    //This method reads in the names from the file into an array
    public static int readNames(Scanner keyboard, String[]names) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
             names = new String[15];
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                names [i] = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println(names[i]);
                count++;
            }   
        return count;
    }


}


My methods print, but the while loop is silent.
```

Comment: please add a language tag  (java?)

Comment: Also, is there more code to your while loop? it looks like your missing the end brace.  Not sure if you had more code there that you wanted to share.

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally cut off the last brace when i copied the code.

Comment: Please share entire code.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the text file. @Sanjay: Note that `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve] & that people asking questions had best not add their 'entire code'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the while loop this line:

```
read.nextLine();
```

performs the line reading but does not store it anywhere.
Also I see loops not needed and creating a 2nd `Scanner` object, for what?
You need to read all the lines inside the array `names` and then loop through this array to extract the last names.
This could be done in a single loop while reading the file, but for readability I use 2 loops:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final int TOTALNAMES = 15;
    int cntr = 0;
    String [] names = new String[TOTALNAMES];
    String [] firstname = new String[TOTALNAMES];
    String [] lastname = new String[TOTALNAMES];

    File file = new File("Names12.txt");
    Scanner  read = new Scanner(file);
    printHeading();

    while(read.hasNext() && cntr < TOTALNAMES){
        cntr++;
        names[cntr - 1] = read.nextLine();
    }

    read.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < cntr; i++){
        //firstname[i] = names[i].substring(0, names[i].indexOf(" "));
        lastname[i] = names[i].substring(names[i].indexOf(" ") + 1);
        System.out.println(lastname[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've made this so much clearer for me. I kept getting null return so I added a second scanner when all i had to do was store my values!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is your count variable and your while loop condition. You never assign a value to count in main, then later you assign a value of 0 to j then execute the while loop only when count

Comment: but i returned count from the method. and i assigned a variable count to the method. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the part where you assign a value to count. However since the condition in your while loop has &&count<j the condition will never be true as j is zero and count is positive or zero. That's why your while loop body doesn't execute